# What is Workflow management using Maven?

Tags: maven, workflow

I have only little experience using maven with eclipse. One of the job descriptions which I received has "Workflow management using Maven" as a required skill. What does this mean ? What do they possibly expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they want you to correct them? :D

I'm not sure what they refer to. I would guess it relates to the developer workflow of creating and delivering software with eclipse (?) and maven.

So setting up a project from scratch is often done from an maven archetype (a project template if you like). A lot of open source frameworks offer archetypes to start with.
For existing projects you would check out the code from version control and import it into eclipse. the m2eclipse plugin is required to do that (but I think its quite common to have it)
Then there is building the software. Which is done through executing maven phases (which will then execute plugins). See [maven-phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for more details. Maven phases have default plugins that execute (for example compile will run the compiler plugin).

So your workflow would look like this: you modify the files. compile them, test them, package them, deploy the artifacts into the maven repository. the maven install phase will store the artifacts in you local repository, the maven deploy phase will upload them into the company's repository.

From there the the files are installed. Yet you can use maven plugins to install the software into a application server. That depends on the traditions of the company.

I would not think of workflow as some strict step by step think like BPMN. Development is usually done with huge amounts of personal practices (are tests written in advance or while implementing, and so on).

Hope that will help :)